# How to add UDF to MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql

I followed this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15643/MySQL-User-Defined-Functions) and it explains how to write the code for the UDF that will be used in the MySQL later .

But it does not explain :

1.Where am I going to compile it ? VS ?

2.What is the expected output ? DLL ?

3.Where to put the output file ?

4.How to add it in the MySQL server ?

5.How to test it ?

please tell me the answer to any of these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find answers to all these questions in official mysql documentation in [Adding a New User-Defined Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-udf.html) section. In brief:

1. It's platform dependent. Visual C++ compiler on Windows
2. Yes, shared library (DLL on Windows)
3. In `lib/plugin/` directory of mysql distribution:

   show variables like 'plugin_dir';
4. `CREATE FUNCTION function_name RETURNS type SONAME 'shared_library_name';`
5. Write SQL test cases. For debug use your preferable debugger.